# Socket is busy when connecting before bind

Tags: node.js, zeromq

I'm using [zeromq](http://www.zeromq.org) to push messages from node.js server to my worker. I create a `router` socket on the node.js side

```
var sender = zmq.socket('router');
sender.bind('tcp://127.0.0.1:6633', function(err) {
  if (err) {
    console.log( 'Error binding socket' );
    return;
  }
  console.log('OK!');
}
```

and connect to this address with a `dealer` in the worker code.

The problem occurs when the worker connects first, before bind (not always, but very often). This should not be a problem regarding the zeromq documentation, so I think it's a problem in the [node.js binding](https://github.com/JustinTulloss/zeromq.node), the question is how can I solve this?

Also a problem that I can catch this exception `Socket is busy` in `process.on('uncaughtException',...)`, not in the `bind` function

I should mention that I'm doing this on windows 7 64bit.

Comment: What problem occurs exactly?

Comment: You could also try rewriting the same thing in Python or some other language and see if the problem is still there.

Comment: @tchap The router fails to bind with this message. I haven't had such problems with similar codes(however haven't tried to convert the same code... I'll try, good idea).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is probably that you are using bind() where you should in fact be using bindSync(). When you read the sources, you discover that the async bind() in fact [locks the socket](https://github.com/JustinTulloss/zeromq.node/blob/master/binding.cc#L519) and [checks the lock every time](https://github.com/JustinTulloss/zeromq.node/blob/master/binding.cc#L330) you do anything with it. What you are probably experiencing is that a worker connects before the socket is unlocked and so it throws an exception. Just replacing bind() with bindSync() worked for me. That is, however, not an idea solution I guess, or rather not very node.js-ish. Let's demonstrate what I mean:

```
var zmq = require('zmq')
  , sender;
sender = zmq.socket('router');
sender.bind('tcp://127.0.0.1:6633', function(err) {
  if (err) {
    console.log( 'Error binding socket' );
    return;
  }
  sender.close(); // This is fine! The socket is ready!
});

sender.close(); // This is wrong! The socket is not ready yet!
```

So you can either call bindSync() and don't care, or call bind() and continue the work in the callback, but you definitely can't use bind() and continue without waiting for it to finish. bindSync() makes the code simpler to read, but you block the whole node.js instance during the call. So I think that the bind() way is more clean in a way that node.js should be used...

Hope this helped ;-)

Comment: What's the best way to wire up 2 async binds/connects so that a callback runs only after both connects. This is a classic async callback mountain problem isn't it? Does ZMQ support promises?

Comment: I guess you could just prepare 2 promises and resolve one in one `bind()` callback and the other in the other `bind()` callback. Then you can usually do something like wait for a list of promises, which in this case would incorporate the 2 promises mentioned.